# Can xml resource files be updated from a server without shipping an app update?

Tags: android

If I ship an app with a few xml data files (i.e. locations with GPS co-ords, etc) can I update these data files without having to ship an app update?  I'm thinking of adding a version tag in res/xml/locations.xml and then periodically checking with a server in WWW land to see if the file needs updating.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/res/` folder is reserved for specific Android resources (layouts, drawables, strings, etc).  Also you cannot write to this folder during runtime, so you cannot update your data file directly.

One approach is to put your initial data xml in the `/assets/` folder and copy it to [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).  Then the app can check the server and update/replace the file as necessary.

Comment: They can also be copied out of /res (e.g., /res/raw).